# How do I get rid of this error 405 ? (Flask/Py)

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I want to make a chat application with Flask and socket.io, but I keep getting an error 405 whenever I click on "send". I've been trying to make this work, but it just won't (just a basic thing with a username and a message). Here is what the error says:

> "Method Not Allowed
> The method is not allowed for the requested URL."

I don't really know what's wrong. When I check my cmd, I see:

> POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 362 0.001000
> 127.0.0.1 - - [28/May/2021 16:44:29] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=7392cec39d5841bcaa7d7c8faaa1b6fb
> HTTP/1.1" 200 0 3.134387

main.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template #Importation du modèle flask et de render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO #Importation du modèle socketio

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] =b'\xba!\xe3];\xce\xe6V}\x1d\xee\xda\x03\x8b\xbfS\xb9\x0fE\x8f\x15\x98O\x92' #Clé secrète afin de garder la partie client sécurisée
socketio = SocketIO(app)


@app.route('/')
def index(): #Définition de la fonction index
    return render_template('index.html') #Affichage de la page index.html


def messageReceived(methods=['GET', 'POST']): #Définition de la fonction message reçu
    print('Message reçu')


@socketio.on('my event') 
def handle_my_custom_event(json, methods=['GET', 'POST']): #Définition de la fonction message envoyé
    print('Mon événement a été reçu: ' + str(json))
    socketio.emit('Ma réponse', json, callback=messageReceived) #Émission du message


if __name__ == '__main__':      #Boucle permettant à l'application web de continuer de fonctionner à l'infinie
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Chat Flask</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='index.css')}}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="para1" style='color: #9cd374;font-size: 30px;'>Pas de message...</p>
        <div class="message_holder"></div>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <div class="inputs">
            <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Nom d'utilisateur"/>
            <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="Message"/>
            <input type="image" id="send" src="static/send.png"/> 
                <!-- Utilisation direct du <style> car le css ne fonctionne pas pour les entrées -->
                <style>
      input[type="email"] {
        text-align: center;
      }
      input[type="text"] {
        text-align: right;
      }
      input[type="tel"] {
        text-align: left;
      }
      body {
        text-align: center;
      }
      label {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
      }
    </style>
            </div>
        </form>
        <!-- Script JS nécessaire pour utiliser socketIO -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var socket;
            $(document).ready(function(){
                socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/chat');
                socket.on('connect', function() {
                    socket.emit('joined', {});
                });
                socket.on('status', function(data) {
                    $('#chat').val($('#chat').val() + '<' + data.msg + '>\n');
                    $('#chat').scrollTop($('#chat')[0].scrollHeight);
                });
                socket.on('message', function(data) {
                    $('#chat').val($('#chat').val() + data.msg + '\n');
                    $('#chat').scrollTop($('#chat')[0].scrollHeight);
                });
                $('#text').keypress(function(e) {
                    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
                    if (code == 13) {
                        text = $('#text').val();
                        $('#text').val('');
                        socket.emit('text', {msg: text});
                    }
                });
            });
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you were using this blog: https://codeburst.io/building-your-first-chat-application-using-flask-in-7-minutes-f98de4adfa5d

At first you should try to follow the guide without any modifications. When you have a working solution, then you can make small adjustments, one by one and always check if it still works, until you are confident using the technology.

Some problem that I see at first glance:

- `io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/chat');` but on your server, you have defined it without path, so you should only use domain + port: `'http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port`
- You have defined what type of messages you are listening to on server side: `@socketio.on('my event')` , but you are sending different events in JavaScript: `socket.emit('joined', {});`
- The same goes for the other direction. On the server you are emitting events to client-side with type `socketio.emit('Ma réponse', ...`, but on the client side you are listening to events like: `socket.on('status', ...`

Comment: I tried with the original content and it didn't work. This time it didn't gave me an error but just didn't show any message or else

Comment: @Mazhaa add console.log for websocket related methods, or better yet: debug in your browser's developer console. Locate at which part are you seeing messages and from which part you don't. It looks to me, that you are also missing an HTML element, which ID is 'chat', so there is no container to insert new HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

To address the main question: your route / only accepts GET requests by default. If you want to allow POST requests, you should adapt this line like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def index(methods=['GET', 'POST']):
```

You may need to do the same in other functions.

Answer (score 0):

It will be a great help if you could paste the entire log but after I saw your index.html, I think you ran into the very same problem as mine.

In your index.html, you used pretty old socket io JS client (1.3.6):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
```

Maybe you look closely in the terminal, it said (which you omitted):

```
"The client is using an unsupported version of the Socket.IO or Engine.IO protocols (further occurrences of this error will be logged with level INFO)"
```

To solve this, please refer to this table that is available on flask-socketio [installation guide page](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#installation):

[image: flask-socketio compability table]

Answer (score 0):

I've just got the same problem and I solve it by changing the tag html from input to button and changing the javascript function .submit to .click

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="send_sample">Sample</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#send_sample').click(function(event) {
    socket.emit('be_send_sample', {data: 0});
});
```

I don't know if it is the best way, but this is how I managed to make it work.
I hope it helps you.